# JavaFX for Ubuntu 16.04 not installed

Tags: java, openjdk, javafx

I tried to install javafx for ubuntu as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34243982/why-is-javafx-is-not-included-in-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-wily-15-10?answertab=active#answers) but the libraries it mentions were not added to my jdk folder after the installation.
Specifically only the *ant-javafx.jar* is added.
My ubuntu is 16.04 and I have the openjkd-8 installed.

Comment: I found this solution to work for me since filebot program requires javafx and openjkd-8 didn't install it by default. [This solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1187110/1030353) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue, solved after reinstall.
Try to reinstall JDK from oracle. As they says:

> As of JDK 7u6 JavaFX is included with the standard JDK and JRE
>   bundles.  Please download the JDK or JRE to use JavaFX.

Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation/jfxpub-installation.htm)